# How do I require a minimum version of zsh?

Tags: zsh

I want to use a feature only present in newer versions of zsh:
 `[[ "$foo" =~ "regexp" ]]` where regexp is a regular expression.

Is it possible to do this check?

Something like:

```
if [[ $ZSH_VERSION > 4.3.9 ]]; then
   ....
fi
```

Except that `>` won't work.

Ciao!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just found `is-at-least` but I'm not sure if it is available in all/many versions of zsh.

Usage:

```
autoload -U is-at-least
if is-at-least 4.3.9; then
   ....
fi
```

It's described in `zshcontrib`.

Ciao!

Comment: According to the ChangeLog and the Git mirror of the CVS history, the first version of `is-at-least` dates back to 2000-02-11 and was first released in either 3.1.6-dev18 or 3.1.6-dev21.

Comment: Awesome! Do you have a link to these resources?